# Can you run a blender game on an iphone or droid?

Tags: iphone, android, blender

I have an iPhone and am getting the Droid and was wondering if blender games can run on either of them. I have already made a game and want to be able to use it on my phone.

Comment: Whoops, I flagged this question as belonging to superuser, but it really isn't. We're not talking about games with/about blenders, but games created with http://www.blender.org/

Comment: http://www.blender.org/ it's 3d software that has a built in game engine you use python or logic bricks

Answer (score 6):

****UPDATE****
I was wrong, just recently android support has been added but it's brand spanking new so just know that android support would be considered beta quality if that, perhaps even alpha.

I can't believe no one has given this answer:

http://code.google.com/p/gamekit/

Supports the logic bricks/python scripts etc so basically you can just load up your packaged blend file and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

there is actually a [book on how to integrate blender into a iphone game development workflow](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470574925). it uses [sio2](http://sio2interactive.com) for the game engine on the iphone. it might be worth to give it a shot.

Comment: is this still allowable in light of the recent 'do it our way or go home' SDK rules?

Comment: It seems that library is written in C or C++, so it should be okay.